# duvida bloquear transição de paginas via URL

Tags: java, jsf

Estou com uma duvida gostaria de saber como faço para bloquear qualquer tipo de transição de paginas via URL independente do usuário estar logado ou não, por exemplo se estou na pagina home.xhtml só poder ir para outra pagina se clicar no botão referente a ela, pq atualmente se estou na home.xhtml e na URL eu coloco por exemplo geral.xhtml ele vai para pagina geral e gostaria de impedir isso, se alguém puder ajudar fico grato.

Answer (score 0):

Eu penso que o bom seria utilizar o JAAS para tratar tanto a autenticação como a autorização de acesso ou o Spring Security ou o Apache Shiro e configurar ROLES e grupos de usuários.

Porém se o controle for simples você poderia criar um PhaseListener do JSF onde você pode interceptar as fases do ciclo de vida, um exemplo é a fase de restauração da view(PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW), poderia criar uma lógica para que quando o recurso que for acessado estiver sendo realizado por um usuário que não esta logado no sistema ou que não tem devida permissão de acesso a página poderia redirecionar ele para a página de login(caso o mesmo não esteha autenticado) ou se ele já estiver navegando mas não deveria ter acesso ao recurso poderia exibir uma mensagem amigável. Abaixo adicionei um link tem um exemplo de um controle bem simples, que apartir dele acredito que possa adaptar ao seu modelo, melhorar e utiliza-lo caso não opte por um controle mais rigorozo com as tecnologias que mencionei acima.

[Login PhaseListener](https://gist.github.com/dilnei/2dfd28353391a9117189)